# Looking for function syntax to check dataframe column against two different dictionary key / value pairs?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, type-conversion

Dictionaries to compare to:

```
PositiveKey = {"{":"0", "A":"1", "B":"2"} 
NegativeKey = {"}":"0", "J":"1", "K":"2"}
```

Current DataFrame:

```
Column 1
0  000000002758A
1  000000326588B
2  000000000567J
```

Desired DataFrame:

```
Column 1
0  275.81
1  32658.82
2  -56.71
```

I am trying to find a way to check if the last character within a data point of a specific DF column matches against two dictionaries (*categorized as needing a status as positive or negative*). Depending on which dictionary key the last character of the data point matches with:

1. I need the data point to be updated with the corresponding value and the overall data point to be defined as a positive or negative integer. (*IE line 0 should be "2758**1**" and line 2 should be "-567**1**"*)
2. I also need the data points to be updated to move the decimal place two spots left. (*IE line 0 should be "275.81" and line 2 should be "-56.71"*).

I suppose converting the data points to integers and then multiplying by +/- .01 or dividing by +/- 100 could work here? Any input is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: What is `"{": "0"`?

Comment: The dataframe I am showing is an abridged version of the actual one I need to work with. In the actual larger one, some of the characters that are presented as the last spot of the data point may appear with the bracket as that character. For instance, the data point in line 1 might read as "000000326588{" instead of "000000326588B" for some data points. Each character, be it a letter or bracket, represents a specific numeric value.

Comment: Is it always the last character?

Comment: Yes, it is always the last character that needs to be manipulated

Answer (score 1):

You're idea is right using `pd.eval`:

> I suppose converting the data points to integers and then multiplying by +/- .01 or dividing by +/- 100 could work here?

```
keys = {'^0+': ''}
keys.update({f'{k}$': f'{v}/100' for k, v in PositiveKey.items()})
keys.update({f'{k}$': f'{v}/-100' for k, v in NegativeKey.items()})

df['Column 2'] = pd.eval(df['Column 1'].replace(keys, regex=True))
```

Output:

```
>>> df
        Column 1  Column 2
0  000000002758A    275.81
1  000000326588B  32658.82
2  000000000567J    -56.71

>>> keys
{'^0+': '',
 '{$': '0/100',
 'A$': '1/100',
 'B$': '2/100',
 '}$': '0/-100',
 'J$': '1/-100',
 'K$': '2/-100'}
```

Comment: Hi, unfortunately, I got an error that reads "EOF in multi-line statement, (2, 0)". I'm not exactly sure why I am receiving that error, as I have double-checked all of my brackets/parenthesis multiple times now. Will keep researching as it clearly worked in your answer provided as well as my "dummy test" jupyter notebook. Thank you for your help so far!

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a function to `'Column 1'`:

```
def get_number(x):
    if x[-1] in PositiveKey:
        return float(x[:-1] + PositiveKey[x[-1]]) / 100
    else:
        return - float(x[:-1] + NegativeKey[x[-1]]) / 100
    
df['Column 1'] = df['Column 1'].apply(get_number)
```

Output:

```
   Column 1
0    275.81
1  32658.82
2    -56.71
```